# Replace whole word string in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a list of country names.
I'd like to rename the country from "Republic of Korea" with "South Korea"
Below is my code

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace('Republic of Korea', 'South Korea')
```

The problem is that, there are 2 countries with "Republic of Korea"

1. Democratic People's Republic of Korea
2. Republic of Korea

And both of them are replaced. I only want to replace #2 but not #1.

I'm trying to use regular expression

```
energy['Country'] = re.sub('Republic of Korea', 'South Korea', energy['Country'])
```

But it gives me error

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `re.sub(r'Republic of Korea' ...` ? Prepending the regexp with `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` to match the start of the string & `$` to Match the end of the string

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ["Democratic People's Republic of Korea", 'Republic of Korea']})
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r"^Republic of Korea$", 'South Korea')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                 Country
0  Democratic People's Republic of Korea
1                            South Korea
```